# facebook api php - access token

Tags: php, facebook

When i'm getting all the info from a specific access_token one of the array elements is:

```
[app_id] => ******
[is_valid] => 1
[profile_id] => *******
[application] => *****
[user_id] => ******
[issued_at] => 1375454193
[expires_at] => 0
[scopes] => Array
```

It's suppose to have this -> [expires_at] => 0?

Comment: This is the info you get from facebook? Such a `0` value probably means it never expires. If it is supposed to be `0` I can't tell you.

Comment: Yeah, i'm getting all this info from Facebook.

Comment: It's weird, cause there alot of talking about "extended access token" or "long-live access token"..and then i see this lol

Comment: In the debugger -> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ -> i allway see that access_token never expires...